# Forge Viewer - Error while uploading file

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I am trying to upload a file with a valid `token` and scope `data:create` and data:write. But I am getting the following error each time.

> {"reason":"No write access"}

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer <token>" --header "Content-Length: 175577746" -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --header "Expect:" --upload-file "test.nwd" -X PUT https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mybucket/objects/test.nwd -k
```

Before uploading the file, I created a bucket which was successful.

Can anyone please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to upload the files, however getting following responce when checking the SVF file conversion job status.

{
    "type": "manifest",
    "hasThumbnail": "false",
    "status": "failed",
    "progress": "complete",
    "region": "US",
    "urn": "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "name": "LMV Bubble",
            "hasThumbnail": "false",
            "status": "failed",
            "progress": "complete",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "type": "error",
                    "message": "Translation failure",
                    "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
                }
            ],
            "outputType": "svf"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

I created an entire post on all the steps you need to achieve the uploading process that you are going through.

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/tutorial-using-curl-2-legged-authentication-model-translation

Check it out and if you still need help, please let me know. Also make sure you have started your trial services so you have access to the Model Derivative API so the translation process works.

Comment: Ironically, clicking your blog link gives me a _You are not authorized to access this page._ error.  I am logged into my forge account and such.  Interested to see this blog post!

Comment: Ok this should not be happening, let me check why and I will get back to you soon.